# Visual studio clear line

Tags: visual-studio

I want to **clear** the current selected line in visual studio (with a hotkey). I know that Ctrl + (Shift +) L removes the the current line, but that's not what I want. 
Example of how I want it to work:

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

I was only able to find hotkeys that remove the selected line and place the cursor on the previous or next line. Yes, I could just remove the line and create a new one, but I'd prefer to use a single hotkey (vs or resharper)

Comment: home, shift end delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the following C# command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension and assign a shortcut to it:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineStart");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineEndExtend");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Delete");
}
```